# Three graphics with tables of data

Tags: tables, floats, diagrams

I need to create a figure like the following. If I have the color plots saved as png images (ie. test.png, rans.png and ddes.png), what would be the best way to create this sort of graphic in LaTeX?
[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility would be to use, inside a `figure` environment, a `tabular` with three columns and two rows environment to position the six elements. I used the `dcolumn` package to get alignment at the decimal point in the data tables; I also used the `booktabs` package for the data tables; in particular, no vertical lines are allowed (this is just a suggestion, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}{D{.}{.}{3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{image1}
& \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{image2}
& \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{image3} \\[1ex]
\begin{tabular}{cL}
\toprule
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{cL}
\toprule
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{cL}
\toprule
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
text & 0.234 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\caption{A figure with three images and three tables}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: That will work. Thanks! (I wasn't aware of the demo option either. That will be handy until I have final graphics.)